# Can the repelling force of magnets be used to create heat energy thus maybe creating a tyoe of heat generator

Tags: magnets

Imagine holding two magnets in the opposite polar the force it creates is so powerful what happens if we hold someting in between and the force only gets stronger if you push  but what if we get a coil and put in a cone magnetize it grab the best heat resistent metal there shape a ball drop it itll start to heat up once hot enough that heat could maybe be used to power something

Comment: Check out eddy current braking. But some formatting would not go amiss.

Comment: I guess I should ask why? Do you somehow expect it to generate heat for free?

Comment: Hi @user32888. Welcome to engineering. I am having difficulty in understanding your question. Would it be possible to rephrase it, and maybe punctuate it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. The magnetization energy stored in a magnet cannot be pulled from the magnet as heat, and even if it could, the magnet would be left dead and to make it work again, you would need to re-magnetize it. No free lunch here.